# In Rails, simple graphQL-ruby queries are ignoring sort order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

The following simple query is not returning `Posts` ordered by `created_at` -
According to the terminal, Rails is ordering by `id`, no matter what i put in `::Post.order(column: :direction)`

```
Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts ` 
                ORDER BY `posts `.`id` ASC LIMIT 24
```

I can't imagine what could be reordering the query by `:id`, or blocking sort order.

Here's the resolver:

```rb
module Resolvers
  class Posts < Resolvers::BaseResolver
    type Types::Models::PostType.connection_type, null: false
    description "List or filter all observations"

    def resolve
      ::Post.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
end
```

Base resolver

```rb
module Resolvers
  class BaseResolver < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver
  end
end
```

Query type

```rb
# graphql/types/query_type.rb
require("graphql/batch")
require("loaders/record_loader")
require("search_object")
require("search_object/plugin/graphql")

module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    field :posts, Types::Models::PostType.connection_type, null: false, resolver: Resolvers::Posts
```

Query (using Relay style cursor pagination)

```
query getPosts {
  posts {
    pageInfo {
      startCursor
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        thumbImageId
        textName
        where
        when
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The app schema:

```rb
class MyAppSchema < GraphQL::Schema
  query(Types::QueryType)
  mutation(Types::MutationType)

  default_max_page_size 24
  connections.add(ActiveRecord::Relation, GraphQL::Connections::Stable)

  # GraphQL::Batch setup:
  use GraphQL::Batch
end
```

Background: I'm planning on using a resolver for this model query because the eventual version will have a lot of filters built with `search_object_graphql`, and while testing the sorting filters i noticed it was ignoring the sort order. So I stripped the resolver back down to the graphql schema inheritance, hardcoded the query scope with an orderby clause, and it's still not ordering the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

This is a documented behavior of the Search Object plugin for graphql-ruby.

I redid my query filters without this dependency, and sort order is working.